# python- Finding difference between values in a dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

If I have a dataframe full of companies that appear multiple times because the data covers a few years how can I find the difference in balance between years for every company?

Example

```
    name        year        balance  
    google      2015        100000
    apple       2015        10000
    dominos     2015        100
    google      2016        1000000
    apple       2016        1000        
    dominos     2016        10000
    google      2017        500000
    apple       2017        500        
    dominos     2017        5000
```

How can I add a column named 'difference' where I can see the difference in balance from last year for each company?

Example

```
name        year        balance        Difference
google      2015        100000         0
apple       2015        10000          0
dominos     2015        100            0
google      2016        1000000        900000
apple       2016        1000           -9000
dominos     2016        10000          9900
google      2017        500000         -500000
apple       2017        500            -500
dominos     2017        5000           -5000
```

If anyone could either show me a way to do this or point me to a resource that shows me I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use, [`DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) on column `name` then use `diff` to find the successive differences, then use [`Series.fillna`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) to fill the missing values with `0`:

```
df['Difference'] =  df.groupby('name')['balance'].diff().fillna(0)
```

Result:

```
df
      name  year  balance  Difference
0   google  2015   100000         0.0
1    apple  2015    10000         0.0
2  dominos  2015      100         0.0
3   google  2016  1000000    900000.0
4    apple  2016     1000     -9000.0
5  dominos  2016    10000      9900.0
6   google  2017   500000   -500000.0
7    apple  2017      500      -500.0
8  dominos  2017     5000     -5000.0
```

Comment: Was too slow, but had the same answer :)

Comment: Perfect answer.  +1